# Assigning stage viewport?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am following [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/03/11/LibGDX-Tutorial-10-Basic-networking.aspx) tutorial and i cannot get the stage drawn to the screen (or the viewport/camera) set correctly. Given i'm rather new to stages and scenes the line below does not compile:

```
stage.setViewport(VIRTUAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT,false);
```

I changed it to:

```
stage.setViewport(new ExtendViewport(VIRTUAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT));
//or
stage.getViewport().update((int)VIRTUAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, (int)VIRTUAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT, false);
```

No errors but no results either.

I took the files (default.fnt, default.png, uiskin.atlas, uiskin.json and uiskin.png) from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data) which should be all of them afaik. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Viewport wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

The easiest is probably to use `stage.setViewport(new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT))`.

Updating in case of a UI stage, should look like this: `stage.getViewport().update(screenWidth, screenHeight, true)`. You don't update with the virtual width and height, but with the real screen size. It's the viewport's job to scale your virtual resolution to the screen/window resolution.

Comment: This does not render anything. Like you said, the above attempt with update does draw but incorrectly.

Comment: Oh I actually need both of those lines. Thank you.